# subscribe to a url to add event in ical

Tags: iphone, ios

I Want to add my events that is in my server into ical using eventkit. Can I subscribe to a url programatically so that all the event can be sync in ical app automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Synchronization is done from your side (Inside objective "c"). You need to fetching all events from server after hitting appropriate URL.
Parse it and save single event with the help of below method:  

-(void)addingEvents{

    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

    event.title     = <<Event Title>>;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:<<Your event date>>];

    NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];

    [dateFormatter release];

    event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:startDate];
    event.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:event.startDate];
    NSArray *alertArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-300]];
    event.alarms = alertArray;

    [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err;
    [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];  
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"Error occured : %@",[err localizedDescription]);
    }
    [eventStore release];

}
```

Comment: but i need to subscribe a to a url like we can do manually with facebook .ics and google also provide this. I just want to add this .ics programatically.i can do this manually by opening the ical app and subscribe to the url.